# Has anyone had success with Visual Studio 6 on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, windows-7

VS6 popped off a series of errors before bombing out completely during install on Windows 7. I specifically need to get VB6 functioning on Windows 7. Anyone having any luck?

Comment: not saying this is a wrong question.. but, VS6?

What do the errors look like?  You might need to try a VM.

Comment: One of many people maintaining legacy VB6 code; this is probably not an uncommon scenario, especially now that Windows 7 is looking like it might be a reasonably decent system.

Comment: It is do-able, I have it going on my machine (Honestly I never use it!) can't remember the procedure however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Folks on the VB6 newsgroup [report](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/browse_thread/thread/91906802150aa029/5f4c093ca2d5ece3?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=%22windows+7%22+ide#5f4c093ca2d5ece3) they have managed to get it working on Windows 7.

There's [this step-by-step guide](http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=20502) on how to install the IDE on Windows 7 (including 64 bit).

If that doesn't work (scrapes barrel) try this old [tip](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2004/07/14/10069.aspx) about persuading the install not to install the Java VM? *Link is now broken so here is the tip:*

> Before trying to install VB6. Create a new file, name it msjava.dll and place it in your windows directory. The file can be zero length.  You can then happily install without the prompt to install an old version of Microsoft's flavour of Java. Once you have installed VB6, delete the msjava.dll otherwise windows update will prompt you to update it.

Or (scrapes hole in barrel) [these tips](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/09/14/vista-versus-vb.aspx) from an article about getting the IDE working on Vista?

Footnote: if developing with ADO, be aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9094786/588306).

Comment: What is the old tip about persuading the install not to install the Java VM?

Comment: Ah - I see the link is now broken. I've edited the tip into the answer

Comment: Creating MSJAVA.DLL didn't work for me, but copying the install CD to my hard drive and blanking (but leaving) "VmPath" in SetupWiz.ini did the job.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I've found that works is Windows XP mode (i.e. a virtual machine). Works fine there, but otherwise, not at all.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, although IIRC XP mode requires hardware virtualisation support on the CPU.  If you don't have that you could try VMWare.

Comment: Certainly not the case for everyone - I installed in no issue on Win7 64 bit

Comment: @MattWilko: So in your opinion pointing out that XP Mode makes it easy is counter-productive?

Comment: Your answer implies that you can't install unless in XP mode which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

I found ALL the answers in a thread at vbmonster.com. As mentioned above, you CAN install Visual Studio 6 with Service Pack 6 under Windows 7 by following Derek's detailed instructions at fortypoundhead.com.

I had a problem because I needed to install Service Pack 5. I use a third party program that does not work with Service Pack 6. A really smart programmer (GuideX) came up with [a great hack to get around the MDAC 2.5 error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/cd740951-dd2c-46eb-856f-6e653a2e3d07).

Answer (score 2):

Win 7 64 bit service pack 5 & 6.  Turn compatability off and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had to debug an ancient application written in Visual C++ 6.0 on Windows 8.1. Tried different solutions all of them failed, only [this](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx) one worked.

This guys made a special installer that allows installing VC++6, VB6, and SP6 on Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10 without any errors whatsoever.

Hope it would be helpful to someone.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, as a link may go down any minute. Please edit your answer to contain the relevant parts of that page.

Comment: If the link goes down, the solution goes down also. The solution consists of downloading the installer from that site and following its documentation. If this it not appropriate to stackoverflow or it's not helpful feel free to discard my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I installed VB6 on Windows 7 Pro without having to use compatibility settings or run as administrator.

Doesn't really help you, but does show that it can work.

Comment: When you say VB6, do you mean the development environment? Did you do something special like only install VB6 without the rest of the studio?

Comment: Yea I only use VB so that's the only bit I installed, didn't install SourceSafe either

Answer (score 1):

Several people in my office have installed Visual Studio 6 (without VC++) on Windows 7, both 32-bit and 64-bit with no problems.  The one thing we have in common:  we've all turned UAC down to it's lowest setting.  Nothing else special required.

Answer (score 1):

I am using vb6 on windows 7 32 bit system for a long time. 
you will need to install your vb6 with compatibility of xp2.

Create a 0-byte file in the C:\Windows directory called msjava.dll.

Don't just install via the Autorun executable; instead browse the Visual Studio 6 CD (or folder), right-click Setup.exe and select Run As Administrator.

On any Program Compatibility Assistant warnings, click Run Program.

Step through the setup screens until you're able to choose Custom Setup, then click next.

On the setup options, install the following items and nothing else:
Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0

ActiveX

Data Access
Graphics

Click continue and the process will start, and (hopefully) eventually complete.
Skip the installations of the MSDN CD, BackOffice, VSS and SNA Server, and clear the checkbox for "Register Now". Setup should be complete.

Download the VB6 Service Pack 6 from        http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=A8494EDB-2E89-4676-A16A-5C5477CB9713&displaylang=en and install.

Change the compatibility settings for Visual Basic (to get it to run a little more smoothly under Windows 7) by browsing to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98, right-clicking the VB6.exe file, and selecting properties.

On the Compatibility tab, check the following:
Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3)

Disable Visual Themes

Disable Desktop Composition

Disable display scaling on high DPI settings

When you start up the IDE, you may get a notification saying that the color scheme has been changed to Windows 7 Basic, but it will be changed back to Aero once you exit. Everything should be working fine at this point!

Note: when you first run your new install vb6 run it with admin rights and with xp2 compatibility so that your exe can run on any system.

Answer (score 1):

The word "supported" is used loosely in this thread, potentially leading the unwary reader to the conclusion that *Microsoft* supports the VB6 IDE (that is, the integrated development environment) on operating systems beyond Windows XP. This fact clearly is stated in the table that appears on the page at this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikosan/2012/04/20/support-statement-for-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8-updated/

Note that executables developed using VB6 are in fact compatible with Windows OS's from Windows XP through Windows 10--32/64-bit versions:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/22/getting-ready-for-windows-10-sdks-compatibility-bridges/

Anyone using non-standard methods to coax the IDE into working on OS's that Microsoft does not support is exposing themselves/their organizations/their employers to risk and is not suitable for risk-averse organizations.

Having said that, I think the purest solution is to install Windows XP onto a virtual machine and run that VM in a modern host OS, such as Windows 10. That works just fine, and you can install directly from the VB6 Setup disc without making any pre-install/post-install customizations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Vista x64 box with a working copy of the VB6 IDE (which was supported). I upgraded the OS to Windows 7 x64 and the VB6 IDE still works fine. You could try that. I know, a huge PITA and kludgy but still, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I run Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit, installed Windows Virtual PC - XP Mode, and that solved my problem isince I can run MSDEV 6.0 in the XP Window.

Not esay to install XP Mode though, the MS site is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

The VB6 programming language is supported on the Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Visual Vasic 6 applications run and the VB6 IDE installs and works too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the VB6 IDE running OK on Win-XP-16, Win-7-32, Win-7-64, Win-8.1-32, Win-8.1-64, win-10-32 and win-10-64 by using the instructions above which basically say, turn off UAC, run the installer AS ADMIN, and then set the VB6.exe file to run in XP-SP3 Compatibility mode.

I have had some issues with it and have had to do a bit more googling to solve these but I don't remember any more what those issues or solutions were.

I've even got the VB3 IDE running on the 32-bit versions of XP, Win-7, Win 8.1 and Win-10 - without even installing them - just copied the C:\VB folder from another computer and copied the *.LIC license files and *.VBX etc files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed vb6 on win 7 32 bit by installing xp first then installing new win 7, (not upgrade), and do not format.  then it will install vb6 without a problem

Answer (score 0):

I have installed VB6 and Visual Studio 6 in Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows 11. Just disable UAC, install normally but unselect Data Access (or unselect only ADO, RDS, and OLE DB Drivers) when going to "Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise - Custom" page.

Answer (score -3):

It's depending on your build version of Windows 7. 
If your Win7's version is lower or is not updated, it has **MANY PROBLEMS** with compatibility.
But mine is newer Win7 version and has **NO COMPATIBILITY TROUBLE**.
I am currently using VB6 , VS6 and they still work fine!
If *Properties->Compatibility->Windows XP* doesn't help, **fix it with UPDATING** your Win7.