# Visual Basic 6 installer for x64 bit machine

Tags: vb6

I wanted to know is there any seperate installer of VB6.0 for 64-bit machine or it will always acts a 32-bit activeX dll each time or is there any by which we can create x64-bit activeX component????

Answer (score 3):

You can install VB6 on a 64 bit machine (my windows 7 box has it installed) but it will run as a 32 bit application (there is no 64 bit version of it)

ActiveX is based on the COM architecture and this will only ever be 32 bit

Answer (score 3):

The VB6 runtime [is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708) on 64-bit Windows. But it will always be 32-bit.

> Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files are 32-bit. These files ship in 64-bit Windows Operating Systems... 32-bit VB6 applications and components are supported in the WOW emulation environment only. 32-bit components must also be hosted in 32-bit application processes.

The VB6 IDE is not supported on 64-bit Windows but [many people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit) use it without problems. Although you can only build 32-bit apps.

Answer (score 2):

There is  no VB 6 for 64-bit AFAIK You can probably implement 64-bit active-X controls with VB.Net.