# VB6 Application Development using 64 bit OS

Tags: vb6, 32bit-64bit, visual-studio-6

My company is looking forward to install 64 bit development PCs. A lot of current projects/applications are written in VB6 and there is no plan whatsoever to upgrade these to .NET.

The current VB6 applications are written on a 32 bit architecture and when installing these applications onto a 64 bit PC, they all run fine after a little tweaking to ensure the applications write to/read from the correct registry locations (e.g. SysWOW64) and 'Program Files' directory (e.e. Program Files (x86)).

My understanding is that Visual Studio 6 is 32 bit software and runs on a 64 bit OS (using the 32 bit layer on Windows - WOW).  Visual Studio 6 will always run as a 32 bit piece of software.

Can I compile VB6 applications to run as/target 32 bit and 64 bit architecture?

How valid is this link: http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Visual_Studio/Compiling_64_bit_apps_using_Visual_Studio_6_and_Windows_Platform_SDK

Please could someone provide a couple of useful links that I could get references from regarding my questions. Thanks in advance.

JFB

Comment: Your company ought to upgrade.  VB6?

Comment: Sure seems on topic to me.  As stated below there is no option to compile VB6 programs to 64-bit.

Comment: This question is very much related to prgramming. Why is it closed as off-topic?

Comment: The link mentioned in the question is probably for Visual C++. I could not even find such screens in VB6 IDE.

Comment: If this question is closed as off-topic, then why is this question allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit? Seriously, the moderators need to think!

Answer (score 3):

The link you provide only refers to Visual C++ 6.0.

You can't create a 64 bits program using VB6.

The VB6 IDE is not supported on Windows 7 64 bit, but you CAN get it to work.  See interesting tips in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit) and details on how to install it in [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2010/11/16/installing-visual-basic-6.0-on-windows-7.aspx).

I have personal experience from supporting VB6 programs running on Windows 7, and as you say yourself, it works just fine.  Personally however, I use an old XP box as a VB6 development machine, mostly because I have one with all the tools installed :-).