# How to install VB6 SP6 on Windows 8.1 x64?

Tags: vb6, installation, windows-8.1, windows64, service-pack

Need to support some old projects directly in the newest OS, not in a virtual machine.

I've installed VB6 from the VS6 disk #1 successfully, but I cannot install the SP6 for this development environment. When I launch it, an information window that informs me about the installation progress appears for some milliseconds, but the required files (ADVPACK.DLL, msvbvm60.dll, ...) aren't updated in the system folder. The About dialog in VB6 IDE also proves that - I do not see "SP6" anywhere in it.

How to install the SERVICE PACK 6 (not the VB IDE itself) in this OS?

Comment: @Jonathon: If I needed to launch it in a VM, I would have not asked such a question. I need to do that directly in Windows 8.1.

Comment: @the_drow, the links are useless. I need to install SP6, but the resources tell me nothing how to do that.

Comment: As I suspected, they are not an answer but they do specify that they are attempting to install VB6 SP 6 with the IDE. What's wrong with installing the IDE as well?

Comment: @the_drow, read carefully the question - there is no problem with installing the IDE itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved my "problem" - very strange why I couldn't figure out what files I needed and what I should have done...

Downloaded and unpacked this (Vs6sp6.exe, I have only VB6 installed):

**Service Pack 6 for Visual Basic 6.0**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721

Then launched setupsp6.exe with the admin rights explicitly - and it installed the SP6 without any problems.

Comment: Does it actually work? Can you run the IDE, build an application and run it?

Comment: @Jonathon, yes, it really works. At least, I could compile the exe and OCX of my real-world projects without any problems. Don't forget to set the 'Run as administrator' checkbox for the VB6 shortcut in the Start menu to avoid problems with accessing the Windows registry.

Comment: I do not have vb6 installed on my Win7  x64 computer. I followed your instructions above (three tries) and everytime get error after installing:  Setup was NOT completed successfully. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ClayNichols, what exactly trouble do you face? And I have just published a link to an article on the Raymon.CC blog as one more answer to this question. Read it. Perhaps, the recipes from that article will help you to solve your problems.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 6 + VB6 SP1 Installation

1. Ensure UAC has been turned off.
2. Ensure your user has administrative rights on the computer.
3. Run the Setup.exe file in the Visual Studio Installer.
4. “Run the program without getting help” when the error “This program has compatibility issues”.
5. Click Next, Accept the Agreement and click Next.
6. Enter your software key, name and company name. Click Next.
7. Update Microsoft Virtual Machine for Java.
8. “Run the program without getting help” when the error “This program has compatibility issues”. Note message shown twice.
9. Say “Yes” to reboot the system.
10. On start up the setup continues to run.
11. “Run the program without getting help”
12. Start Page shown. Click on Desktop.
13. “Run the program without getting help”
14. Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Edition shown with options “Custom, Products or Server Application”.
15. At this point click “Exit” on the installer and confirm with “Yes” otherwise an error will be shown if you continue.
16. Run the Setup.exe file in the Visual Studio Installer.
17. “Run the program without getting help”
18. Click Next and Accept the Agreement and click Next
19. Enter your software key, name and company name. Click Next.
20. Select Custom and click Next
21. Installation folder click next
22. “Run the program without getting help”
23. Click “Continue”.
24. Product ID click “Ok”
25. Tools -> Change Options -> OLE/Com Object Viewer, Uncheck and click OK.
26. Enterprise Tools -> Change Options -> Visual Studio Analyzer, Uncheck and click OK.
27. Data Access -> Change Options -> ADO, RDS and OLE DB Providers, Uncheck.
28. At this point it warns saying the component is essential. Click OK and OK again.
29. Click continue.
30. Say Yes to register environment variables.
31. Say Yes to VSS DB format.
32. Install box with “Destination File:” should appear.
33. Setup is updating your system message box should appear.
34. Click OK to Windows NT Debug Symbols.
35. Click Restart Windows.
36. On start up the setup continues to run and loads APEMREG.exe.
37. Install using compatibly settings.
38. “Run the program without getting help”
39. Untick install MSDN. Click Next and yes to confirm.
40. Select Nothing and click Next.
41. Select Nothing and click next.
42. Untick Register and click finish.
    SP6 Installation
43. Run setupsp6.exe
44. Click Continue.
45. Click I Agree.
46. Setup Successful click OK.

Read more: http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=23916#ixzz3i6JHcNMg

Comment: when I try to run Setup.exe at step 3, Windows 8.1 says "This app can't run on your PC".

Comment: Are your running the Setup.exe? or is it the Autorun? Have you got a screenshot?

Answer (score 6):

**How To Install Visual Basic 6 (VB6) in Windows 10**

***Get your system prepared***

There is a need to prepare a file MSJAVA.DLL in your system directories so that the installation of VB6 could proceed. In terms of doing this, just get the installer VBPreInstall.exe and execute the installer.

***Install VB6 and SP6***

After getting MSJAVA.DLL ready, you can launch the Visual Basic 6 setup.exe file with administrator privilege to start the installation.

1. Accept agreement, product key
2. Enter name and company information, click **Next**.
3. Select **Custom Setup**, click Next.
4. Click **Next**, wait for another windows pop up, click **Continue**, then Ok.
5. Setup will “think to itself” for about 2 minutes. Processing can be verified by starting Task Manager, and checking the CPU usage of ACMSETUP.EXE.
6. On the options list, select the following:
   Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0
   ActiveX
   Data Access
   Graphics
   All other options should be unchecked.
7. When you select **'Data Access'**, you need to click the **Change** Option button.
8. You will then get another list of components with only 5 items. Select the first option “ADO, RDS, and OLE DB Providers” and click the **Change Option** button.
9. Now you’ll get another list of components that belongs to the ADO, RDS and OLE DB Providers. Simply **uncheck** the first option “ADO and RDS” and click OK.
10. You should get a warning that this component is an essential part of the application and the application will not run properly if it is not installed. You can ignore that warning popup by clicking **OK** and proceeding with the installation. The VB6 installation setup should now complete successfully without problems.
11. **Uncheck** MSDN setting
12. Click **Next** to skip the installation of Installshield. This is a really old version you don't want anyway.
13. Click **Next** again to skip the installation of BackOffice, VSS, and SNA Server. Not needed!
14. On the next dialog, **uncheck** the checkbox for “Register Now”, and click Finish.
15. The wizard will exit, and you're done. You can find VB6 under Start, All Programs, Microsoft Visual Studio 6. Enjoy!

***Install VB6 SP6***

Install vb6 sp6 by navigating to VbSp6, run setupsp6.exe as administrator with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

There is an installer to simplify the installation of the VB6 programming IDE on Windows 7, 8 and 10 which has now had over 25,000 downloads. This includes Service Pack 6

[VB6 programming IDE installer](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Home/tabid/36/language/en-US/Default.aspx)

Comment: There is an explanation of how to install the VB6 programming IDE on Windows 8.x here...

     http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=23916

Comment: where is the download?

Comment: I haven't been able to get that website to let me login and download it.  The last step in the process is to confirm your email address and I never got the email. (I registered a few weeks ago and I don't see email with "vbcorner" in it. Just tried again, no new email in the last few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried both methods here on Windows 8.1 Update 2. At first the symptom had been the same as the OP, except that I was doing exactly what the OP did as his solution -- extracting the files and running Vs6sp6.exe.

So I tried the other solution, installing MSDN. After MSDN installed, I tried SP6 again. This time, it tells me it can't install because it can't find any VS6 products installed. But VB6 (without SP) still starts up fine. Also MSDN starts up normally.

Any suggestions? If I have to run it in a VM I will; I already have Windows XP on a Hyper-V VM for the original early 90's Oxford English Dictionary. But it would be a lot more convenient if I could get it working directly in 8.1.

BTW I've been running it fine in Windows 7 for years. There are some hoops to go through to get it installed, and it changes the screen when it starts and stops, but overall not bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

While you can run VB6 in Windows 8.1 it's not going to do well and there will be any number of issues as you've discovered.

An alternative option is to create a Virtual Machine using Hyper-V Manager which is [readily available on Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/hyper-v-run-virtual-machines), install Windows XP*, Visual Studio 6, etc. Then remote desktop to your virtual machine and you're good to go.

Also, when windows 9, 10 and 11 arrive, your virtual machine can be transferred over to them or to a new PC all without breaking your VB6 development environment.

*Or Windows 7 32 bit if you have to but XP is better for VB6

Comment: Utter nonsense, sorry.  Besides not being a problem, you have to have VB6 installed natively in order to program against the new APIs and components.

Comment: I'd have to agree with the above comment. Reason being that we have the virtual machine and its a pain in the a#* and it doesn't represent the real world users as most people these days would have at least windows 7 if not 8 or 10. However, i have not yet successfully installed VB6 on my Windows 8.1 machine. Though i will be doing this soon.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid approach and worked well for me using a W7 VM. (Alas now that W7 support has ended I can no longer use it on the corporate domain).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three simple steps:

1. Install VB6 first
2. Install MSDN complete
3. Install VB6 SP6 only after installation of MSDN

You will be able to install VB6 SP6 successfully.

Comment: Thanks.  Installing the MSDN Library seemed to help.  SP6 installed cleanly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found one interesting article that describes how to install VB6 in Windows 10 in the Raimond.CC Blog:

**How To Install Visual Basic 6 (VB6) in Windows 10**

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-visual-basic-6-vb6-in-windows-7-without-microsoft-virtual-machine-for-java/

As you can see from the title, the author gives us an advice how to avoid installing the needless VM for Java. Another useful advice in this article allows us to prevent “Setup is updating your system…” progress from getting stuck.

Read this article. Perhaps, it will help to solve problems with installing VB6 in your OS.