# VB6 install on Win10 Anniversary gives Insufficient Memory

Tags: vb6

Attempting to install VB6 Dev into Windows 10 Anniversary.
Downloaded VB6 from MSDN.

If I try to install, either from ISO or from extracted files the install fails when run both as admin and non-admin…

Error: Setup initialization error.  There is insufficient memory to run setup.  Try closing any open applications or restarting Windows.

Attempted:

- Stack overflow search
- Admin mode
- Compat mode + win7
- Compat mode + admin mode + win7
- Compat mode + admin mode + win8
- compat+admin+w7, acmesetup to compat+admin+win7

[image]

Comment: Seen this: http://blog.danbrust.net/2015/09/14/installing-visual-basic-studio-6-on-windows-10/#.WFHGDLLaf4Y ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Install VB/VS 6.0 IDE on Windows 10 isn't simple.
I've developed a free tool to help user for this.

See the my official web-site:
**Visual Studio 6 Installer wizard**
http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx

However, the VS6 Installer wizard latest version **4.8** is under developement and test, due to Microsoft changes the 'rules' at each build.
The OS version under test is: **Windows 10 Pro/Home 1703 (march 2017)**

Comment: I wound up shimming it in, but had found your tool (afterwards!).  Great stuff, thank you very much.