# Run Visual Studio 2002, 2003, and VB6 side-by-side on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, vb6

I am upgrading my machine to Windows 7 but I would still be supporting VS2002 (.net 1.0), VS2003 (.net 1.1) , and VB6 applications.

Is it possible to load these VS and VB6 applications, build, compile, edit code, and support this source code in Windows 7?

Comment: I have managed to do so. But the debugger failed on me a couple of weeks ago in vs2003 against IIS. I do know the usual trickery but it was to no avail. So; it might work (with some hacking). Might not, its unsupported etc.

Comment: This question is partly a duplicate of [has anyone had success with VB6  IDE on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7). In short, yes: see answers on the other question for tips on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to answer your question is to do an experiment.  You can setup a VirtualBox whose guest OS is Windows 7, then put whatever programs inside and test out.  If they run fine, it's okay to do the real upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
Refer here
http://www.vbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vb/33424/VB6-on-Windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You need a virtual machine. Sorry. You could always see if the virtual machine in Win7 works - but failing that, do what I did and create a virtual machine running XP and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've used VB6 and VS2003 on Vista in the past, so there shouldn't be a problem with 7. I'd second setting up a VirtualBox or maybe try VirtualPC to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Even if for some strange reason you weren't able to install the development tools, you could (assuming you're using a high enough edition) use Windows XP mode for those tools that you couldn't get to run natively under Windows 7.