# Unable to install VB6 and Service Pack 6 in Windows 10 64 bit OS

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 application which needs VB6 Service pack 6 for running and debugging. When I try to install VB6, the installation doesn't complete successfully and it hangs at the end. But we can still open VB6 and compile the code. Service Pack 6 doesn't run successfully. Because of this there are issues while running the code.

One such issue is unable to read data from MS Access (.mdb files). Error Message: "Couldn't find installable ISAM"

My OS is Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation of VB6 on Windows 7 (or Windows 8) (or Windows 10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495680/installation-of-vb6-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-or-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)