# Getting error message - "Unexpected error, quitting" while opening the VB6.exe

Tags: windows, vb6

I am not able to run Microsoft Visual Basic (VB6) in my system. I am continuously getting error messages - Unexpected Error, quitting.

[image]

*(Visual Basic was not able to start up due to an invalid system configuration. Missing or not registered VB6TMPL.TLB)*

[image]

*(Unexpected error; quitting)*

Also I am not able to install VB6 Setup.exe in my windows10 64 bit system. Always getting "Not Responding" screen.

[image]

I tried to install VB6 setup.exe multiple times, but it is always going to Not Responding screen and not getting installed.

Comment: Did you turn off UAC and run Setup.exe with "Run As Administrator"?

Comment: Also, I believe the last time I did a VB6 install on W10 it hangs, but you just end task and it works.  Been a while tho.

Comment: Related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495680/installation-of-vb6-on-windows-7-8-10

Comment: fwiw, this application is no longer supported by MS. They literally don't care if a random windows update breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you got a error while running VB6.EXE, because it may be:**

- You haven't copy the [source directory]:\OS\SYSTEM files to %WINDIR%\System32.
- You doesn't setup the registry settings.

I was tried VB6 without attempting for do both, and the result was it, with another error.

**But, "Working Model Version", that mean it's running from CD without running setup.exe**

**You can install VB6 or Visual Studio 6 in Windows 10 without "Not Responding" screen:**
[Install Visual Studio in Windows 7 or later](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191047/Install-Visual-Studio-on-Windows)

Comment: What do you mean that you can't run it directly from the VB98 folder? That's where it is always run from...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).