# How to Compile Visual Basic 6 code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba, vb6

I have a project of Visual Basic 6.0, in that I have some code changes. for that I need Old Visual Basic 6.0 IDE that I don't have.

So anybody can me tell me that,

Is that possible to compile that VB 6.0 code in Visual Studio 2010 and later and how.

Or Where i can get the Visual Basic 6.0 IDE Setup and that i can install in Windows 7 OS.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, you can't compile VB6 projects in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You need a retail version of VB6 to compile. EBay.

Comment: The VB6 IDE is available through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: You could also ask around with colleagues/consultants.  Someone may have a copy installed on an old machine.  Note that you will also need licensed copies of any and all custom controls.  There were (very, very) many available and it was very common for any non-trivial app to use one or two.

Comment: This question is about [how to install VB6 IDE on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7) and this is about [how to install it on Win 7 64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the IDE first, and then:

For installing in Windows 7 you may need to follow the instructions in [this website](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/408806/How-to-install-Visual-Studio-on-Windows-profes)