# Moving VB6 loses its license

Tags: vb6

I know this is not directly a programming question but I use this to create programs so I hope the question qualifies.

I moved VB6 Enterprise to a new computer using PC Mover.

VB6 now runs as "Working Model Edition"

Does anyone know how to move the license or otherwise fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You're stuck on VB6? Condolences. It hasn't updated or patched in over a decade :(

Comment: FYI I use VB6 on Win7 and Win10 for my work, without problems. So there will be some solution to your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Not to use PCMover, simply :
a) Unistall VB6 from old pc
b) Install VB6 into new pc

Comment: Thank you Giorgio. But I tried to use your tool and it fails because Setup.exe will not run - says it has "known compatibility issues" and fails after the first screen. I tried to post a message to you about this but gave up after 4 failed attempts.

Comment: I think you want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7

Comment: This does not mean anything. My VS6 Installer v.4.8 tool (also reported by IT journals) has been downloaded and successfully used by thousands of users (with over 100,000 downloads). My forum is active and working. That's where you have to go.